# Configuration space of identical particles - fractional statistics

Tags: topology, quantum-hall-effect, identical-particles, anyons

In Khare's book of fractional statistics and quantum theory, when discussing why we need fractional statistics he arrives at the configuration space 
[image]

for a system of two identical particles in $d$ spatial dimensions.
**Q1:** I do not see how the second equality is justified. ($P_{d-1}$ is the $d-1$ dimensional real projective space, and $\langle 0,\infty \rangle$=$(0,\infty)-\{0\}$).

Later on, he writes this:
[image]

**Q2:** He seems to imply that $(\mathbb R^2 - \{0\})/\mathbb Z_2 = \mathbb R P_{1}$. But actually $\mathbb R P_{1} = (\mathbb R^2 - \{0\})/\sim   $ with $x\sim y$ iff they lie on the same line. Maybe there is a physical reason to make this identification $(\mathbb R^2 - \{0\})/\mathbb Z_2 = \mathbb R P_{1}$?

Comment: I asked a similar question about $\mathbb{R}^n / \mathbb{Z}_2$ at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2832826/does-identifying-opposite-points-in-euclidean-space-result-in-a-smooth-manifold. I share your confusion.

Comment: Please see my answer, I hope that it is helpful https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/110458/anyons-only-in-21-spacetime-dimensions-better-explanation/110486#110486

Answer (score 2):

Denote

$$ M_d := (\mathbb{R}^d -\{0\})/\{x \sim - x\} \ . $$

To answer Q2: for the equation (2.14) to hold, it is not necessary that $M_d = \mathbb{R}P_{d-1}$. It's enough if these two spaces are homotopy equivalent, which they are. Indeed, consider an equivalence class $[x] \in M_d$. $[x]$ may be written as $e^\lambda [\hat{x}]$, where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\hat{x}$ is a unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Then consider the following map:

$$ F:[0,1] \times M_d \mapsto M_d \ , \quad (t,e^\lambda [\hat{x}]) \mapsto e^{(1-t)\lambda} [\hat{x}] \ .$$

Then $F(0,\cdot) = \text{id}_{M_d}(\cdot)$, but $F(1,\cdot)$ maps $M_d$ on the projective space.